# How to show a .NET Balloon ToolTip?

Tags: .net, winforms, tooltip

How do i show an `IsBalloon` **ToolTip** in WinForms?

Right now i try:

```
ToolTip hint = new ToolTip();
hint.IsBalloon = true;
hint.ToolTipCaption = "Hello, world!";
hint.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
hint.Show("Please create a world.", myTextBox, 0, 0);
```

Unfortunately the balloon doesn't point **to** `(0, 0)` (relative to the control), but shows up **at** `(0,0)` (relative to the control):

[image]

What is the correct way to show a .NET Balloon ToolTip?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028466/c-set-position-of-the-arrow-in-a-tooltip-balloon) related question?

Comment: Not clear from the sentence "Unfortunately the balloon doesn't point to (0, 0) relative to the control, but shows up at *(0,0)* relative to the control."  Which control, ToolTip or TextBox?

Comment: @M.Babcock i had not seen that question; although that question's unrelated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Known bug.  Call it twice, first empty:

```
toolTip.Show(string.Empty, myTextBox, 0);
toolTip.Show("Please create a world.", myTextBox);
```

From [How do I make a tooltip point at a specific label in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627228/719186)

Comment: i had googled, and googled, and you still can't beat someone who remembers the answer.

Comment: @IanBoyd See [ToolTip balloon stem is oriented incorrectly for first invocation of ToolTip.Show()](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98281/tooltip-balloon-stem-is-oriented-incorrectly-for-first-invocation-of-tooltip-show)

Answer (score -2):

Your last line should be.
Mouse_hove Action.

Answer
hint.Show("Hello", Me, Me.PointToClient(New Point(0, 0)), 5000)
'------------------------