# What C# Winforms Control for Application Tutorial

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I've got a C# Winforms application, and I'd like to add a little tutorial for new users. So when they start the application, I'd like a little box to appear next to a button, saying that they should click that button. And when they visit a new form for the first time, using the same approach to draw attention to important controls. As well as text, I'd like this little thing to have a button to dismiss further tutorial messages.

[image: Sort of like this]

The thing is, I have no idea what actual winforms control to use for this. Should I use a Dialog, with a custom border? Or could I somehow use a tooltip that doesn't go away when the mouse is moved? Or is there a different control that I don't know about? Or, even, is there a third party control that will do this?

Comment: I think [ToolTips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) may be good enough. - But you need to think a little more about what exactly you want. To explore the controld on a form the user should move over it and see a helpful message about this control. But when moving to other controls, don't you think the previous helptext should go away? Do you really want the form cluttered with messages all over? Also: Usually the ShowToolTips is a global setting of an application; is that what you want, too?

Comment: That's a ToolTip, like TaW mentioned, with `IsBalloon` set to true, and shown using a `Show` overload that associates it with a specific control window. That way, you get the balloon tip pointing at the control. If you want it to never disappear and are unsatisfied with setting the timeout to the longest permissible value, you need to create a [*tracking* tooltip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298405.aspx). I can't remember if that's exposed by the WinForms wrapper or not. I don't think so. You might have to [resort to P/Invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5891265).

Comment: Do be careful that you don't overdo this, and end up with something like Stack Overflow's [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation), with the throbbing blue dots everywhere. You are generally better off making your user interface as obvious as possible, rather than trying to include just-in-time help everywhere. If someone really doesn't know where to start, that won't help them. They'll need actual documentation. For self-starters that like to just jump in, and are otherwise fairly computer savvy, all these popping bubbles will mostly just annoy them.

Comment: Two further notes: ToolTip doesn't have an event for clicking it so you can't implement those buttons. And: When shown as Balloon you can't OwnerDraw it, so you can't add images or format the text.. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529753/InteractiveToolTip-Tooltips-you-can-click-on) is a poject for a clickable ToolTIp

Comment: This is NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip() at work.  Use notifications only to notify the user about things he can 't easily find out another way and are important enough for him to pay attention to.  Like an almost-empty battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't think of a way to do it with built-in controls, you can make a borderless unmovable form and make it look like a tutorial box.

Comment: You need to add the detail of how to implement your suggestion to make an answer useful. Simply saying 'you can make' doesn't really help.